# How to configure production connection string on .NET Web API on Digital Ocean app platform

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core-webapi, digital-ocean

I have recently deployed a **PostgreSQL** cluster on **DigitalOcean**. I have also uploaded a **dockerized .NET Web API** application on **App Platform**, which I now want to connect to my database cluster on DigitalOcean. Within my API I have a connection string (set up for development environment) that connects to my local PostgreSQL database. As far as my knowledge goes, once I deploy my API on App Platform the environment becomes production. I have tried using the environment variables on **App Platform** to configure that but I did not succeed. The error that I’m getting in the Runtime Logs is :

> An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter
> ‘connectionString’)

The error points to the place where I call my connection string in .NET - Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql().AddDbContext<DataContext>(options =>
{
 options.UseNpgsql(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
});
```

What I tried was adding an environment variable with the key value being the name of my connection string **(DefaultConnection)** and the value being the connection string of my Managed PostgreSQL (**"User ID=XXXXXXXX;Password=XXXXXXXXX;Server=XXXXX;Port=XXXX;Database=XXXXXXXXX; Integrated Security=true;Pooling=true;"**). I also tried using quotes for the value of the environment variable but it also did not help. Any advice on this issue will help me a lot.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone that experiences something similar, I was able to solve it by using `ConnectionStrings__DefaultConnection` when defining the environment variable key in DigitalOcean App Platform.

Comment: You should accept your answer as it saved me lots of time!! Thanks for finding it - are there any docs on the topic?